# Attach lifecycle of two objects in swift

Tags: swift, oop

I am writing code to read data from a temporary sqlite file, I am creating a `Connection` (`SwiftSQLite` object) object, and I want to somehow attach an object to the lifetime of this `Connection` object (which I did not write) so I could delete the file once the `Connection` object is out of scope.

Initially I thought of doing this using inheritance and adding my logic to the destructor, but unfortunately, `Connection` is declared as `final` for some reason.

Is there any way to do this? something like keeping a secret reference to my object inside the `Connection` object, so when the `Connection` object is being freed, my object's destructor will also be called?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly than I think a simple composition will do the trick.

```swift
final class FileBoundConnection {
  private let connection: Connection
  private let filePath: String

  deinit {
    // close the connection
    // delete the file
  }
}
```

Obviously inject whatever dependencies you need for the connection / deletion in initializer. It'd also be best to have `FileBoundConnection` mimick the API of `Connection` (or even create a protocol mimicking it) so that your switch over to the new type will be as painless as possible.

If this is your only reference to `Connection` then when `FileBoundConnection` goes "out of scope", so will `Connection` and you will be able to act on it.